# Extracting first initial and last name

Tags: strings, powershell

How can I do this better?

```
$a = "Tom Smith" ; $e = $a.substring(0,1)
$ee = ($a).split(" "); $y = $e + $ee[1]; $y
TSmith
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to review code like this because the code you are showing seems to be example code, which means that some context has been stripped away. Unlike Stack Overflow, we prefer to look at real code instead of example code. Please see the meta question: [Why is hypothetical code off-topic for Code Review?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243). You should also define exactly what the purpose of your code is, and think about some edge-cases that can occur. What about names without a space? What about names with two spaces?

Comment: Also note that this is a cross-post from Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29525542/1310566

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are another option:

```
$name = "Tom Smith"
$short = $name -replace "(?<=^.).*\s", ""
$short
```

The above code replaces the second character, through to the last space, and replaces them with nothing (deletes them).

The regular expression is what's called a zero-width positive lookbehind - [See a tutorial here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

The following examples/outputs:

```
Tom Smith      -> TSmith
Tom Bob Tables -> TTables
 Bob           ->  Bob
```

If you only want to remove to the first space (so `Tom Bob Tables` becomes `TBob Tables`, then add a `?` to the expression like `"(?<=^.).*?\s"`